# Concatenating lists inside a LINQ query 

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

My data structure is set up this way

- A user takes a number of modules
- A module contains a number of courses

Here's how the relationship looks like:
[image]

How do I get a list of courses the user takes?

The query I have now is:

```
  var courses = (from ClassEnrollment enrolment in entities.ClassEnrollment
                       where enrolment.UserID == UserID
                       join Module module in entities.Module
                         on enrolment.ModuleID equals module.ID

                         select module.Course
                     ).ToList();
```

However, this doesn't result in a list of courses, but rather a list of list of courses.

How can I flatten this query to a list of distinct courses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var courses = from ClassEnrollment enrolment in entities.ClassEnrollment
              from module in entities.Module
              where enrolment.ModuleID equals module.ID && enrolment.UserID equals UserID
              select module.Course
```

Comment: How is different from my original query?

Comment: @Extrakun: It should flatten the results since it uses `SelectMany` under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

According to your data structure screenshot, you have a one-to-many relationship between the `ClassEnrollment` and `Module`, as well as navigational property called `Module`. You also have a many-to-many relationship between `Module` and `Course`, but the navigational property should be called `Courses`. Given your code, you want something like this:

```
var courses = entities.
              ClassEnrollment.
              Where(e => e.UserID == UserID).
              SelectMany(e => e.Module.Courses).
              ToList();
```

Your question, however, mentions a user: `A user takes a number of modules`, `How do I get a list of courses the user takes?`. I don't see any User entity anywhere else, though, so it would be nice if you could clarify. Are you using LINQ-to-SQL, btw?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework. I didn't add an association between ClassEnrollment and User to begin with, so I didn't include that in my screenshot. Now thinking of it,  I think I should add in the association.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

courses.SelectMany(c => c);

In your query you don't need explicitly specify the type for the range variables

Or you can join course to the query

```
var query = from enrolment in entities.ClassEnrollment
            join module in entities.Module on enrolment.ModuleID equals module.ID
            join course in entities.Course on module.CourseID equals course.ID
            where enrolment.UserID == UserID
            select course;

var course = query.ToList();
```

Comment: module does not have a courseID, it has the navigational property Course which inside EF is a list of courses the module has association with.